# Postix/Dovecot reject: Relay access denied

Tags: postfix, centos7, dovecot

Under CentOS 7, I have set up `Postfix` and `Dovecot`. I have setup `reverse dns`, as sell as `MX` records, etc.

I am able to send mail to the server fine. However, if I try to send mail from the server, I get this error trail in `/var/log/maillog` times out:

```
Jan 21 00:19:49 xxxx postfix/qmgr[19789]: 2812220F96: from=<xxx@xxxxxxxxx.com>, size=1525, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 21 00:20:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20328]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.192.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:20:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20490]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.192.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:20:49 xxxx postfix/smtp[20328]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.186.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:20:49 xxxx postfix/smtp[20490]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.186.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:21:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20328]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.202.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:21:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20490]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.202.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:21:49 xxxx postfix/smtp[20328]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.206.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:21:49 xxxx postfix/smtp[20490]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.206.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:22:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20328]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.143.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:22:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20490]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.143.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:22:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20328]: 8B1DA20F91: to=<xxxxxx@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=893, delays=743/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.143.27]:25: Connection timed out)
Jan 21 00:22:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20490]: 2812220F96: to=<xxxxxx@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=652, delays=502/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.143.27]:25: Connection timed out)
Jan 21 00:24:49 xxxx postfix/qmgr[19789]: 8065220F97: from=<xxx@xxxxxx.com>, size=1063, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 21 00:25:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20686]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.192.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:25:49 xxxx postfix/smtp[20686]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.186.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:26:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20686]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.202.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:26:49 xxxx postfix/smtp[20686]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.206.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:27:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20686]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.143.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 21 00:27:19 xxxx postfix/smtp[20686]: 8065220F97: to=<xxxxxx@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=690, delays=540/0.02/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.143.27]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Comment: I figured it out. It turns out  my server colo provider blocks SMTP on new accounts!

Answer (score 0):

Your email client attempted to connect to Postfix port 25 and send mail. This is not allowed. You need to connect to port 587 and authenticate to the server (and probably also set up authentication, but you didn't discuss whether you did that).

Comment: I think you are on to something here. See EDIT 1.

Comment: It looks like you didn't finish setting up postfix. The `submission` entry in `master.cf` isn't enabled. I don't know what tutorial you were using, but it was either incomplete, incorrect or for some other purpose.

Comment: I enabled it still doesn't work. I put the main.cf file instead (body limit forced me to erase)

Comment: BTW, as you can see from the main.cf file, I have set up authentication.

Comment: @Ivan I don't see anything relevant to authentication in the main.cf file you posted. Exactly what did you do?

Comment: I actually got much farther! Now I can send mail to the server, however, it gets stuck there. See the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Your latest revision indicates that outgoing traffic on port 25 is being blocked.  Your firewall may also block traffic ISPs often do this for domains that should not be sending email to the internet.   It is difficult to validate your configuration when you don't provide your domain.

You can get an idea of where you are being blocked using a tcptraceroute program to see where you get blocked.   In the mean time try sending via your ISPs email relay.

Original Response: Normally, you would configure your local network (likely something like 192.168.1.0/24) as trusted.

If the host at 50.244.27.204 is truly one of your servers you might want to trust it.  Given that this is an internet routeable address you do risk becoming a limited open relay if this is not your server.

The usually method for allowing access from hosts not on the local network is to use the Submission port (587) to accept authenticated requests.  You should configure authentication to require a TLS encrypted connection started with STARTTLS.

You will see this kind of message from untrusted address, as there are bots out there that will try to use your serve as an open relay.

Comment: This also helps. See EDIT 1. I am pretty sure I am already trusted my own network. I also have Thunderbird to use STARTTLS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have not provided very much information.  Not sure if you are connecting to the server on port 25 or 587.  The log snippet you provided shows no indication of any authentication before sending.  You're an open relay if you allow just anyone to send email through your server (the outbound IP will almost assuredly get blacklisted, not very fun).

All I can see from what you provided is:
Your server is configured to not relay messages from 50.244.27.204 on the port you connected.

To make much more of your request I'd suggest including:

1. Basic info on client config including: server IP (sanitized or changed) and port (not sanitized or changed), any authentication methods chosen, error messages if any you receive on the client when sending fails.
2. More complete mail.log snippet (sanitize or change any IP) but include all messages, especially authentication for 10 seconds before and after the failed send.
3. Copy of master.cf and main.cf (sanitize or change any private information) from the server, usually in /etc/postfix.

Hope this helps,

Comment: It does help. I added EDIT 1.